# Display Elements Based On Logged In User (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I am stuck here. LOL

Basically, I am working on a new RoR project and curious to figure this step out.

I am creating a Dating site for Sugar Daddies/Babbies. (Paid project by another person).

Basically, when a "Sugar Baby" logs in, they can set their;
Date Price | Text Price

What I am trying to accomplish is either;

```
<% if user = User.find_by_email('email_address') %>
<%= render 'users/paypal_buttons/user_email_paid %>
<% end %>
```

It works for the most part.

However, when I add more than 1 user find by email, the display page shows ALL users paypal buttons.

Please advise.

Second option.

Integrate PayPal in order to allow logged in users to create their own buttons in order to set the payment prices.

I appreciate your efforts in advanced.

Here is my code. ** Please Note. Using "babies or baby" in exchange for "user or users"**

Discover User Text

```
<% if current_baby = Baby.find_by_email("b10-h4ck3r@protonmail.com") %>
  <%= render 'babies/paypal_buttons/bio_h4ck3r_text' %>
<% end %>

<% if current_baby = Baby.find_by_email("b10-h4ck3r@icloud.com") %>
  <%= render 'babies/paypal_buttons/b10_h4ck3r1_text' %>
<% end %>
```

Show User;

```
<td>
<%= render 'babies/paypal_functions/discover_user_date' %>
</td>
<td>
<%= render 'babies/paypal_functions/discover_user_text' %>
</td>
```

As mentioned, when I try to view it live, it shows both users PayPal buttons.

Comment: How are you authenticating users?  I take it you are not using Devise?

Comment: No I am not using Devise. It is just basic authentication of Login/Register. Using BCrypt for password security

Comment: You are using an assignment not an equality operator, try `if current_baby == Baby.find_by_email("b10-h4ck3r@icloud.com")` instead.

Comment: @3DPrintScanner Thank you so much! That actually worked for what I am trying to do!